# OS selection menu not appearing on System with Ubuntu and Windows 8 installed

Tags: windows-8

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo G570 with 2nd gen dual core processor with 2 gb ram with Pre installed Windows 8 pro. Whenever i start my system, it automatically loads Windows 8. When i go into msconfig, it shows only 1 os i.e. Windows 8. Everywhere in windows where it shows the installed OSs, it shows only Windows 8 Pro.

I installed Ubuntu on a separate partition of 15 GBs and the installation was successful. I wanted to install Ubuntu inside Windows 8 using wubi but whenever i tried that, my system automatically restarted.

So my problem is that I am not able to load Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried looking at other questions similar to this on the site?

Answer (score 0):

Download PartedMagic and boot from PM live cd,open partition editor and select the partiton where ubuntu is installed,right click and manage flags, check boot. Restart and your laptop will start from ubuntu.